# Laravel Passport Token On Sub Domains

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-passport

I am running multitenancy application based on subdomains and wants to login the user right after the registration.But when I create the token then that token not works 
.But on the other hand, when i login then i gets the token and that token works perfectly.

Following is the flow of my application

- User comes to main domain i.e abc.com 
  User registers I create a new tenant
  for the user with sub domain (test1.abc.com).  Add the user (i.e
  email & pass) in newly created tenant and "generates the token" by
  this command

  ```
  $user = User::create($data);
  $token = $user->createToken('My App')->accessToken;
  ```
- I then return the token and redirect the user to its subdomain.

The token not working and gives me 401 unauthenticated response.

But when I **login** the user (from main domain) i.e abc.com then I again fetch the token and that token works on subdomain. Below is the code for Login

```
    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        $user = $req->user();
        $token = $user->createToken('My app')->accessToken;

        return response()->json([   
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => 200,
            'message' => 'Logged In Successful',
            'data' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
            'redirect_url' => $db->redirect_url
        ] , 200);
    }
```